# Looping through string array items error

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

**Scenario:** I have a mouse pointer code, that clicks on a certain screen coordinate, copies, then clicks in another coordinate and pastes. My data being copied can change, and some columns have problematic information.

**Problem:** Some of the columns have data such as "17-2" or "13.5". So, for these columns, before the copy paste procedure is done, I change the columns in the excel file to txt, with:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Columns("E").NumberFormat = "@"
```

These problematic columns can change place (be "E" or "J", for example), or even not be present at all.

**Objective:** I am trying to alter my code, so I get an user input with the column numbers that must be changed to text.

**Where I got so far:** Assuming that I am using a MSGBox to get the user input (in the form of "2/4/5/9", as a string). I first split that into an array, and not I am trying to loop through this array. For each number in the array, I use a ColumnLetter function, that gives me the required letter of that, and then I change that column to text.

**Issue:** Right now (after checking many posts on how to properly loop through string arrays, here in SO) I got to this code:

```
Dim ColTXT As String
Dim ColTXTArray() As String
Dim i As Long

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

ColTXT = Application.InputBox("Please enter ascending column numbers to be 
changed to text (separated by '/', no blanks)", "Please enter Column 
Numbers")

ColTXTArray() = Split(ColTXT, "/")

For i = LBound(ColTXTArray) To UBound(ColTXTArray)
    'ColTXTArray (i)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Columns(Col_Letter(ColTXTArray(i)))_
.NumberFormat = "@"

Next i
```

But I am not being able to do this procedure, looping through each item in the array.

**Question:** What would be the best way to do this?

**Obs:** In my last run, I got an error in the line (ByRef argument type mismatch):

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Columns(Col_Letter(ColTXTArray(i)))_
.NumberFormat = "@"
```

**Obs2:** This is my function to find a column letter based on a number:

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
Dim vArr
vArr = Split(Worksheets("Output").Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), 
"$")
Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Comment: Your `Col_Letter` function excepts a Long while you have declared `ColTXTArray` as String.

Comment: @SJR Changed it, now I get an Object Type error.

Comment: ^^ Plus why do you do `.Columns(Col_Letter(ColTXTArray(i)))`?  Why not just do `.Columns(CLng(ColTXTArray(i)))`?  It seems strange to convert a number to a character just so that Excel can look up its mapping table to convert it back to a number again.

Comment: @DGMS89 - when you say you changed it, do you mean you changed `.Columns(Col_Letter(ColTXTArray(i)))` to `.Columns(Col_Letter(CLng(ColTXTArray(i))))` (which would probably work) or did you change `lngCol As Long` to `lngCol As String` (which won't work unless you also change `.Cells(1, lngCol)` to `.Cells(1, CLng(lngCol))` )

Comment: @YowE3K Why, you ask? Because I stupid, hahah. That works perfectly (your first comment), and I have no idea how it works. Care to write it as an answer?

Comment: That looks like an awful amount of work, considering that the process is automated (haha). (1) Why can't you treat all cells as text? (2) Why can't you identify the items which need special treatment by macro? (3) are you aware that `'2-17` (with a leading apostrophe) will write "2-17" into the cell as a string? Accordingly, you never have to set the Numberformat property. Just add a leading apostrophe or not. If you can't add it for all, I'm sure a macro can spot the need where to add it faster than your user who enters the column numbers.

Comment: @Variatus Ideed that might work. The point is that my macro just copies and pastes, it does not access each item individually. Some columns might have errors (usually less than 10% of the data in that columns), by that comes from their nature. I could also change all columns to text, but some columns are then used in calculations, and some are dates (in this case, changing them to text causes additional problems). About the ', I did not know, thanks for the tip. I will check if I could use it somehow.

Comment: Presuming that all columns are text (whether by format or by apostrophe) you could prevent non-numeric values to be processed by testing before using them for further calculations. "13.5" (as a string) would be numeric and could be processed as 13.5. "2-17" would be processed as 2, skipping the non-numeric "-" and whatever follows. But you must have a filter preventing strings from being calculated already. Therefore these problems are already being dealt with - or perhaps not?

Comment: @Variatus My code has problems with the data when it is not pasted as a text column because it changes the data for some reason. For example, if I don't paste the 17-2 as text, it is changed to a date format, which causes problems later on. So the quickest way I found to avoid this, is to change the column to text without pasting.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. That's why I advocate examining if you can change all values to text. Numeric text can be calculated just like numbers. It's just to get around the need for someone to sit and determine which columns to format as text.

Comment: @Variatus Yes, I understand. But the problem in that case would be the dates. My original data has a US format (05/25/2001). When I change it to text, it pastes it like that, but if I leave it as general, for some reason, I get 25/05/2001. I know this is not a hassle to fix, but considering the amount of data, I prefer to avoid it altogether.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142840/discussion-between-variatus-and-dgms89).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Columns` collection can be indexed either using a text index, e.g. `Columns("D")`, or by a numeric index, e.g. `Columns(4)`.

There is therefore no real need to have a `Col_Letter` function in your code, you can just refer to the column using

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Columns(CLng(ColTXTArray(i))).NumberFormat = "@"
```

(The `CLng` is converting your `String` value, e.g. `"4"`, to a `Long`, e.g. `4`.)